# The name 'CreateDirectory' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have seen several forms of my question, so I think it must be trivial for many. Even I might know how it is being created, however, no idea how to fix it. The error reads as:

"The name 'CreateDirectory' does not exist in the current context"

while I've tried to develop a code behind in ASP.Net via C#. I understand I must probably add mscorlib.dll as reference to the bin, however, MS Visual Studio can not add this dll as it can not convert it to .Net assembly.

The code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class X_Project : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    CreateDirectory("C:\\UploadedUserFiles\\");
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                String filename = FileUploadControl.FileName;
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could anybody help please?

Comment: is createDirectory a custom defined function?

Comment: using System.IO; and Directory.CreateDirectory ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Mitja beat me to it before I could write it out in answer ;). You might find it helpful to google MSDN + the item that is not in context to find out which namespace it is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CreateDirectory is not a defined function. You probably intend to use [System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\UploadedUserFiles")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Obviously you can also shorten that with using statement:

```
using System.IO;
[...]
Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\UploadedUserFiles")
```

Comment: I think this MSDN link is in `Germany` language. Better post English version.